# Error exporting DateRange from react mui/lab

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new with React and I'm trying to use a DateRangePicker from material ui but I have an error exporting DateRange from @mui/lab. I read about a recently migration but I was no able to fix it, here is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Box, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { DateRangePicker, DateRange } from '@mui/lab';

export const DatePickerRange = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState<DateRange<Date>>([null,null]);
    return(
        <Box width='500px'> 
            <DateRangePicker 
                startText='Inicio' 
                endText='Fin' 
                value={value}
                onChange={(newValue) => {setValue(newValue)}}
                renderInput={(startProps, endProps) => (
                    <>
                    <TextField {...startProps}/>
                    <Box sx={{mx: 2}}> a </Box>
                    <TextField {...endProps}/>
                    </>
                )}/>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Comment: The error is: "export 'DateRange' (imported as 'DateRange') was not found in '@mui/lab' (possible exports..."

Comment: Please do also put the error message into your question and the line / context where it is arising

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that `<DateRangePicker>` component has been migrated from Lab and now is available only in commercial MUI X PRO.

https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/migration-lab/